# DCT transform in image processing

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have an image and want to transfer it into discrete cosine transform space and then regenerate the image by using the lowest 25 percent and 56.25 percent and 6.25 percent parts,I know that I can use dct2 in matlab, but I do not know what is the lowest 25 percent of part means and how can I regenerate image by them??

Comment: My guess is that once you arrange the block in zig-zag order after you take the DCT, only use 1/4 of the block, set the rest to 0, then reconstruct the block (reverse zig-zag, then IDCT).  Zig-zag ordering is important because it rearranges the block so that the most important information appears first, followed by information that isn't so important.  If you arrange your block via zig-zag, it'll be much easier to crop off what's important because the most important data is most likely going to appear at the beginning.  BTW, I probably won't write an answer because doing that is a lot of work.

Comment: can you please help me, I really do not know what to do??

Comment: thanks a lot, I really need it.

Answer (score 1):

The DCT is usually performed on an 8x8 block of pixels (64). It sounds like you want to use only 16.

What you would do for each 8x8 block is:
1. Perform the DCT
2. Set 48 pixels to zero

The trick is that you need to keep the transform values in the upper left corner. In JPEG, you work through the DCT values in a zigzag, starting in the upper left corner.

The issue would be which values to keep as you got further away from the corner. I would start by using the values the form a square in the upper left corner so that you are keeping the values close to the diagonal.

Comment: can you please give me the code, I am do not know how to apply it

Comment: I believe matlab uses array indices 1..8. One way would be to  for I=1 to 4, J = 5 to 8  coefficients [i, j] = 0 then for  i = 5 to 8, j = 1 to 8, set [i,j] = 0. Pseudocode.

Comment: am I doing the right thing??img=imread('cameraman.tif');
p1=ceil(1/4*size(img,1));
p2=ceil(1/4*size(img,2));
dct=dct2(img);
dct(p1:size(img,1),p2:size(img,2))=0;
for i=p1:size(img,1)
    for j=1:p2
        dct(i,j)=0;
    end
end
for i=1:p1
    for j=p2:size(img,2)
        dct(i,j)=0;
    end
end

Comment: I don't know matlab but It looks like you are trying to do the DCT on the entire image rather than in blocks.

Comment: yes,is it wrong to do that???I want to implement a method which is said that" The original image is transformed to the frequency domain and the lowest 1/16, 1/4 and 9/16 parts are used for regenerating the image".

Comment: You need to decompose the image into blocks then apply what this answer provider has told you per block... Or what I told you above. `im2col` would be a useful function here.